# Accessing values of function object from within it's nested function

Tags: javascript

Lets say we have function `test()`:

```
function test(){
    a();

    this.b = function(){
        alert(1);
    }

    function a(){
        this.b();
    }
}

var t = new test();
```

This code will throw *TypeError: this.b is not a function*

The question is, how can we correctly access `b()` from within `a()`?

Comment: As I understand now there were 2 problems: this in a() wasnt reffering to test() and invocation of nested function that is using object's properties must be after declaration of these properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the order:

```
function test(){
    var me = this;
    this.b = function(){
        alert(1);
    }

    a();

    function a(){
        me.b();
    }
}
```

You can't call `this.b()` before you've assigned the variable. And you need to use a local variable to capture the value of `this` in the closure.

Answer (score 0):

```
function test(){
  var me = this;

  this.b = function () {
    console.log(1);
  }

  function a() {
    console.log('calling me.b()');
    me.b();
  }

  a();
}

var t = new test();
console.log('calling t.b()');
t.b();
```